# Reference to variable out-of-scope

Tags: c++, scope, reference, return-type, function-definition

I have made the following example to test my understanding of references:

```
#include <iostream>

int test(){
    int a = 1;
    int &b = a;
    return b;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    std::cout << test() << std::endl;
}
```

What I intended to do is to write an example where the referenced variable is destroyed. I originally wrote this thinking that, since the lifetime of `a` in `test` ends when returning `b` in `test`, outputting the return-value of `test` produces gibberish. However, to my big surprise, it actually does output 1!

How is this possible? What am I missing here - can `a` somehow continue living in `b`?

Comment: your function returns a value not a reference

Comment: btw even if you would use an invalid reference you cannot distinguish betwee a gibberish 1 and a non gibberish 1

Comment: Usually it's harder to avoid U.B. than to introduce U.B. but anyway: [demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50c7a7d2ea1b7783)

Comment: Neither `a` nor `b` are alive. Your function returns a copy of the value in `a`. Seems you are trying to understand references before you understand that (by default) return values from functions are copies not references. If you want `test` to really return a reference then `int& test()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function does not return a reference to any object. It returns a temporary object of the type int that was copy-initialized by the value referenced by b.

```
int test(){
    int a = 1;
    int &b = a;
    return b;
}
```

In fact the function is equivalent to the following function without using intermediate variables

```
int test(){
    return 1;
}
```

To return a reference means that the function return type should be a referenced type. Something like

```
int & test()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a;
}
```

In this case the compiler will issue a message that the function returns a reference to a local variable.

Comment: In the last case the compiler *may* issue a message.   The behaviour is actually undefined, which means no diagnostic is required.   Practically, most modern compilers, by default, do NOT issue any message in this case - but can be configured to (e.g.  with command line options to issue more warnings).

Answer (score 0):

I see where your confusion comes from. You think because you are using the (&) operator during the assignment of b that the variable b now contains the memory address of a. This is not the case, the ampersand (&) is mute, meaning it has no effect on variable b in this case.

```
int test()
{
int a = 1;
int &b = a;
return b;
}
```

The behavior you are expecting would look like this

```
int* test()
{
int a = 1;
int *b = nullptr;
b = &a; 
return b;
}
```

In this case you are return b without de-referencing the variable then you would obtain the memory address instead of the number 1.

Comment: _"the ampersand (&) is referencing the address of b; "_ not sure what you mean here. `b` is a reference to `a` and `&` is not the address-of-operator in this case. On that note: your second snippet has the wrong return type.